# SFML, C++, Makefile - Invalid instruction

Tags: c++, oop, makefile, game-development, sfml

I am writing an Arkanoid in C++ using SFML. The fact is that when the game closes, the state of the game changes from the state of the game to the endgame. The game state changes, the game record is entered on the console, but not for a few milliseconds, and the following is entered: make: *** [Makefile:19: all] Invalid instruction (a memory dump was created).

To run the code, you can use the command: make

OS : Archlinux

Pkg version: make 4.4.1-2, sfml 2.6.0-3

Game.cpp :

```
#include "../include/Game.hpp"

Game::Game()
{
    initWindow();
    initFont();
    currentState = std::make_unique<GameState>(window, font);
}

void Game::initWindow()
{
    window.create(VideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), "Arkanoid");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
}

void Game::initFont()
{
    if (!font.loadFromFile("fonts/mont_extralightdemo.ttf"))
        exit(0);
}

void Game::changeState(std::unique_ptr<State> newState)
{
    currentState = std::move(newState);
}

void Game::handleInput()
{
    currentState->handleInput();
}

void Game::update()
{
    currentState->update();

    if (currentState->isGameOver()) {
        int score = currentState->getScore();
        std::unique_ptr<State> newState = std::make_unique<EndGameState>(window, font, score);
        changeState(std::move(newState));
    }
}

void Game::render()
{
    window.clear();
    currentState->render(window);
    window.display();
}

void Game::run()
{
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        handleInput();
        update();
        render();
    }
}
```

GameState.cpp :

```
#include "../include/GameState.hpp"

GameState::GameState(RenderWindow& windowGame, Font& fontGame)
    : window(windowGame)
    , font(fontGame)
    , ball()
    , board()
    , blocks()
    , text(fontGame)
    , score(0)
{
}

void GameState::handleInput()
{
    if (!ballMove) {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) {
            board.moveRight();
            ball.setPosition(Vector2f(board.getPosition().x + board.getSize().x / 2 - ball.getRadius(), ball.getPosition().y));
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
            board.moveLeft();
            ball.setPosition(Vector2f(board.getPosition().x + board.getSize().x / 2 - ball.getRadius(), ball.getPosition().y));
        }
    } else if (ballMove) {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D)) {
            board.moveRight();
        }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
            board.moveLeft();
        }
    }

    while (window.pollEvent(ev)) {
        switch (ev.key.code) {
        case Keyboard::Escape:
            window.close();
            break;
        case Keyboard::Space:
            ballMove = true;
        }
    }
}

void GameState::update()
{
    if (ballMove) {
        ball.move();
        if (ball.getGlobalBounds().intersects(board.getGlobalBounds()))
            ball.setVelocityY(-(rand() % 7 + 3));
        if (blocks.handleCollision(ball.getGlobalBounds())) {
            ball.setVelocityY((rand() % 7 + 3));
            score += 50;
        }
        if (ball.getPosition().y > board.getPosition().y)
            setGameOver(true);
    }
}

void GameState::render(RenderWindow& window)
{
    text.draw(&window, score);
    ball.draw(&window);
    board.draw(&window);
    blocks.draw(&window);
}

int GameState::getScore() {
    return score;
}

bool GameState::isGameOver() const
{
    return gameOver;
}

void GameState::setGameOver(bool value)
{
    gameOver = value;
}
```

EndGameState.cpp :

```
#include "../include/EndGameState.hpp"

EndGameState::EndGameState(RenderWindow& windowGame, Font& fontGame, int& score)
    : window(windowGame)
    , text(fontGame)
    , scoreFinal(score)
{
    text.setPosition(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 9);   
}

void EndGameState::handleInput() {
    while (window.pollEvent(ev)) {
        switch (ev.key.code) {
        case Keyboard::Escape:
            window.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void EndGameState::update() {
    
}

void EndGameState::render(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    text.draw(&window, scoreFinal);
}

bool EndGameState::isGameOver() const {
    
}

int EndGameState::getScore() {
    
}
```

TextGame.cpp :

```
#include "../include/TextGame.hpp"

TextGame::TextGame(Font& font) {
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setCharacterSize(36);
    text.setColor(Color::White);
    text.setPosition(60, 30);
}

void TextGame::setPosition(float x, float y) {
    text.setPosition(Vector2f(x, y));
}

void TextGame::setCharacterSize(int size) {
    text.setCharacterSize(size);
}

void TextGame::draw(RenderWindow* window, int score) {
    text.setString("Score : " + std::to_string(score));
    window->draw(text);
}
```

MakeFile :

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wreorder
SFMLFLAGS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system -lsfml-window

SRCDIR = src
INCDIR = include
OBJDIR = obj
BINDIR = bin
TARGET = main

SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
HEADERS = $(wildcard $(INCDIR)/*.hpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @clear
    @./$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR) -c -o $@ $<

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(SFMLFLAGS)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*
    @rm -rf $(BINDIR)/*
```

I thought the problem was in the text output, but I deleted this variable and nothing changed...(

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the exact command you ran and the exact output you got (if there's a lot of it, provide the last 10 or 20 lines): use cut and paste and format this as a code block so it's clear where newlines are etc.  Second, you should never add the `@` prefixes to your recipe lines until AFTER your makefile works, and you definitely should not add a `clear` command.  Throwing away this critical output makes it hard to debug build problems.  Finally please specify the type of operating system you're using and what version of make you're using `make --version`.

Comment: Also, please provide a [mre] if you need debugging help. We can't compile this and it's also too much code.

Comment: You have quite a few methods that promise to return a value but don't. Isn't your compiler screaming at you to fix them? This is a very probable cause for the "illegal instruction" error you get.